# Normalize phone numbers using regex

Tags: c#, regex, phone-number

I have a list of phone numbers entered by users without validation and they look like:

```
 - 495) 995-0595
 - 105-6439
 - 095 268 8621
 - 324-51-44
 - 7 (495) 995-05-95
 - 7 495 995 05 95
 - 7 (495) 995-0595
 - +7 (495) 995-05-95
 - 7 (495)925-34-89
 - 7(495)9253489
 - 7(495)925-34-89
 - 74959950595
```

I want to convert these numbers into this (Russian) format:
+X (XXX) XXX-XX-XX

Is there any chance here to achieve it using regular expressions?

Comment: I guess you should put validation when user is entering data.

Comment: it looks like u've only got two scenarios, 7 digits and 11 digits. formatting aside, you would first strip all formatting from your list and store as just pure numbers. then format it which ever way you want with string.format

Comment: How do you know what to put in the missing fields for a short number like `105-6439` or `324-51-44`?  Can we assume they are all `+7 (495)`...?  And is a leading `095` a shorthand for `+7 (495)`?

Comment: I guess these numbers are in some sort of database. I don't see any other solution than "normalizing" them: extract the digits and reformat them according to your Russian phone number format.

Comment: If I have numbers like 105-6439 or 324-51-44 I have to format it using Moscow international code (499)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, Extract & Reformat!

```
List<string> oldlist = new List<string>();
List<string> newlist = new List<string>();
foreach(string s in oldlist)
{
     if(s.Contains('(')) s = s.Replace('('), "");//etc
     newlist.Add(numFormat(s));
}

string prefix = "495";

string numFormat(string s)
{
     string my;
     if(s.Length == 7)
     {
         my = string.Format("+7 ({0}) {1} {2} {3}", prefix, s.substring(0,3), s.subtring(3,2), s.substring(5,2);
     }
     else if(s.length == 10)
     {
         my = string.Format("+7 ({0}) {1} {2} {3}", s.substring(0,3), s.substring(3,3), s.subtring(5,2), s.substring(7,2);        
     }
     //etc
     return my;
}
```

This is just off the top of my head... but you get the idea

Answer (score 2):

Run your list through this:

```
var strippedNumbers = new List<string>();
foreach (var num in listOfRussianNumbers.Select(x=>Regex.Replace(x, "[^0-9]", ""))) 
    strippedNumbers.Add(num.Length == 7?"7499"+num:num);
```

Then use string.Format to print it out how you want

```
string.Format("+{0} ({1}) {2}-{3}-{4}", 
    num.Substring(0,1), 
    num.Substring(1,3),
num.Substring(4,3),
num.Substring(7,2),
num.Substring(9,2));
```

Comment: Last 3 ones have to be `num.Substring(4,2),
num.Substring(6,2), num.Substring(8,2));`

Comment: nope, i think ur missing the first number, so all ur strings are 1 char off :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do this

1. Convert it to string.
2. Using Loop remove anything that does not look like number. You can use `Char.IsDigit()` for this.
3. Then do your desired formatting using `string.Substring()`.

Make sure you do all these steps in string format only.

Like

```
string str = "495) 995-0595";
List<char> digits = new List<char>();

for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    if(char.IsDigit(str[i]))
        digits.Add(str[i]);
}

str = new string(digits.ToArray());

str = "+" + str.Substring(0, 1) + " (" + str.Substring(1, 3) + ") " 
      + str.Substring(4, 2) + "-" + str.Substring(6, 2) + "-" + str.Substring(8);
```

This returned me `"+4 (959) 95-05-95"`

Comment: The problem is that the missing round paranthesis in 495) defines the city code number. So I have to fix this miss also, to get the phone number in XXX-XX-XX

Comment: i think you'll find in both Nikhil and my solution that we ignore all the bad formatting. stripping the formatting is alot easier than 'fixing' the formatting. Just grab the numbers and then overwrite it in the correct format. Don't think about trying to fix each individual formatting case, there's infinite possibilities of bad cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I can get in short notice.

```
((\+?\d)\s?)?\(?(\d\d\d)\)?\s?(\d\d\d)(\s|-)?(\d\d)(\s|-)?(\d\d)
```

This will select the bolded from your sample.

**495) 995-0595**
105-6439
**095 268 8621**
324-51-44
**7 (495) 995-05-95**
**7 495 995 05 95**
**7 (495) 995-0595**
**+7 (495) 995-05-95**
**7 (495)925-34-89**
**7(495)9253489**
**7(495)925-34-89**
**74959950595**

On the strings that dont match, you can send them through a different routine or for manual processing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
(\d)? ?\(?(\d\d\d)?\)? *?(\d\d\d) *?-? *?(\d\d) *?-? *?(\d\d)
```